# Parse all logs in a table Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, logging

Is there a Codeigniter library which would parse from logs folder all logs in a table and could filter on debug or error?

like:

```
ERROR    Source of error
DEBUG    output debug
```

Comment: This is the interesting part of being a programmer: Write your own ;) But i never heard of anything like this. maybe you extend the logger-class of codeigniter?

Comment: I have no experience in this, but I found a link to parse error logs. You can customize the solution as you want.: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/191508/#903948

Comment: @Hugo.B certainly you are right but I thought there is a ready made solution than I can spend more time on other issues.

Comment: @balajimca the link is usefull thanks